# Open Source Code in Chrome with VBA

Tags: vba, google-chrome, excel

I've got this so far. Only the Chrome browser opens (which is empty) & it doesn't take into consideration the url. What changes should I make to the Shell script?

```
Sub ViewSource()
  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

  Shell (chromePath & "view-source:http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oGdXgbd8FQJXoAuj6l87UF?p=cars%20parts&fr=sfp&pqstr=car%20parts")
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915325/open-google-chrome-from-vba-excel

Comment: @Daniel I am able to view the URL of the page, but I require to view the source code.

Comment: Missing a space after the exe? - That does not seem to work even when run from the command line ...

Comment: @User124726: aha i see ... sorry did not understood that correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many different flags on Chrome.exe in cmd prompt but non are working.

But you can get the source code this way:

```
Sub t()
GetSource "http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oGdXgbd8FQJXoAuj6l87UF?p=cars%20parts&fr=sfp&pqstr=car%20parts"
End Sub

Function GetSource(url As String) As String

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url
    .Send
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .Readystate = 4
    GetSource = .responsetext
    .abort
End With
```