# Excel VBA on webpage: not filling in a textarea

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, text

I'm stumped. I'm trying to use vba to fill in the description text area with the text "hi" but I'm getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the page:
http://toronto.kijiji.ca/c-PostAd?AdVideoUrl=&AddressCity=&AddressCounty=&AddressRegion=&AddressSelectedByUser=false&AddressStreet=&AddressStreetName=&AddressStreetNumber=&AddressZip=&Alley=&CPUrl=&CatId=212&ChangeCategory=&ChangePhoto=&ContactInfo=&Description=&DiscountPrice=&Email=&EpsErrorCode=&EventEndDay=18&EventEndHour=23&EventEndMinute=59&EventEndMonth=5&EventEndSecond=3&EventEndYear=2014&EventStartDay=18&EventStartHour=0&EventStartMinute=0&EventStartMonth=5&EventStartSecond=3&EventStartYear=2014&GetNeighborhood=&Guid=&JavaScriptNotEnabled=false&Lane=&MapAddress=&Number=&PaypalEmailAddress=&PaypalMobileNumber=&Phone=&Photo=&PhotoDesc=&PostAs=POST_AS_OWNER&PreviewAd=&PreviewToEdit=&Price=&RequestRefererUrl=%2C&RoadStreet=&SelectedLeafCat=SelectedLeafCat&ShowPhone=checked&ShowTerms=&SubNumber=&Thumbnail=&Title=&TransDescription=&TransTitle=&VinNumber=&WebsiteUrl=&action_cancel=&action_publish=&carproof=&cplink=&cpvin=&extraInfo=&machId=&numActiveAdsInCategory=&text_loading=&tmId=&useBasicUpload=false&utm_campaign=&utm_medium=&utm_source=

Here's the element:
`<textarea name="Description" id="hdnDescription" wrap="soft" cols="71" maxlength="100000" style="width:500; height:240;font-family:arial;" ondescriptiondest="0" rows="6" class="tipField"></textarea>`

Here's the code I tried:

```
Sub test()
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate Website
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

' Description
  objIE.document.getElementByID("hdnDescription").Value = "hi"
   End With


End Sub
```

I also tried using getElementsByName instead of by ID but that didn't work either:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByName("Description").Item(0).Value = Description
```

Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

note: also posted here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/785128-visual-basic-applications-webpage-not-filling-textarea.html#post3842132

Comment: I don't know anything about VBA, but try .value instead of .Value

Comment: "I'm getting errors" - what errors *exactly* ?

Comment: @Waxen: VBA never has been case sensitive for the last decade :-D

Comment: @TimWilliams when I use the variation with getElementByID, I have no error but the description simply does not fill.  When I use the variation with getElementsByName, I get the error "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 1):

If I open your URL with Chrome, I see the textarea hdnDescription as you describe.

If I open your URL with IE11, the textarea hdnDescription is rendered invisible but a rich text editor with an IFrame and own HTML content is visible. Why? No clue... but like this, the code line `objIE.document.getElementByID("hdnDescription").Value = "hi"` won't work as expected.

So I've chosen another website with a simpler structure, here: https://www.netvoip.ch/support
The textarea is at the very bottom.

Then, your snippet with this URL works perfectly fine. I see the "hi" appearing in the textarea:

```
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim webSite As String
webSite = "https://www.netvoip.ch/support" 
With objIE
    .visible = True
    .navigate webSite
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

   ' Description
   objIE.document.getElementByID("description").value = "hi"
End With
```

As the mechanism works fine, it could finally be that you have to use it also for Kijiji although the textarea hdnDescription is rendered invisible, because the form submission will take its value anyway.

Comment: Would an easy fix be to open the URL in Chrome instead of IE?
If so, how would I modify my code to achieve that? Chrome is my default browser.

Comment: You can open Chrome by VBA (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915325/open-google-chrome-from-vba-excel), but it won't give you a controllable object. Further, it seems very unstable to me to rely on things like "Standard Browser" - your code would work differently on each computer :-) I suggest you look deeper into that Kijiji page. How many variations of the text editor do you find with different browsers? At the very end, is it relevant? The value of which control is finally submitted to the server? Focus on this control. Does it have to be visible so your code finally works? etc.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Ultimately whether the value is visible or invisible is not relevant for me. But when I submit the form, the website returns an error saying 'you must enter a description' so, visible or not, the value is not going through currently.

Comment: Try to observe the http data sent if you fill out the form correct. Each contemporary browser has an inspect environment with the section "Network traffic". Try to google how to open it. If you dig in a http request, you'll see headers, request, answer and more. Imitating the correct behavior might help here, independently of the rich text editor html helper constructs.

Answer (score 0):

The IE application goes into readyState 4 when the document starts to load. You have to wait for the document readyState as well before you can start changing the DOM.

This is a Sub I use to wait for IE taken from another project.

```
Private Sub WaitUntilLoaded(ie As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ready As Boolean

    ' wait for page to connect
    i = 0
    Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        i = i + 1
        If i > 300 Then
            Err.Raise 513, , "Timeout"
        End If
    Loop

    ' wait for document to load
    Do Until ie.document.readyState = "complete"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        i = i + 1
        If i > 300 Then
            Err.Raise 513, , "Timeout"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Also, it's `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementsByName`.

Comment: So I would add that code as a seperate sub and then call on that sub in my main code?
Also, to be consistent with my main code, would that still work by renaming the "ie" object into "objIE"?

Answer (score 0):

The "description" box resides within an iframe.  Usually, to interact with an element that resides within an iframe you extract the src attribute from the  tag and navigate to the URL formed by that src and the base URL.  Then, on the new webpage, constructions like

> objIE.document.getElementByID("rteDescription").Value = "hi"

should work. However when I try adding the src to the base url, in this case the new page does not have a description box (or anything else) to interact with.  Don't understand why this approach fails in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the tag of HTML **textarea** is:

```
<textarea id="hdnDescription" ></textarea>
```

then use .innerHTML to provide text in textarea, VBA Code to provide text “Hello World”:

```
ObjIE.Document.getElementById(“hdnDescription”).innerHTML= “Hello World”
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
objIE.getElementsBytagname("textarea").Item.Value = "Your text."
```