# Create hyperlink in excel that opens in Chrome

Tags: excel, hyperlink, deep-linking

I am trying to create hyperlinks so that when clicked they will open in Chrome, regardless of what the default browser is.

Can anyone please assist with this

Thank You

Comment: start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915643/6241235    An event may be more successful than hyperlink. Format event target cell as fake hyperlink.

Comment: But would that not only work if the macro is running? Or would that work if someone is just manually using the spreadsheet?

Comment: The idea is you use a sheet event - selection change for the cell formatted as a fake hyperlink.... that would be the target. Selecting the cell would trigger the event which would run the code to pass the url to chrome or have the url already in the code.

Comment: Ok, cool, i guess i just didnt understand, probably a little over my technical capabilities, but as long as i know it should work ill look into getting to grips with this technique. Thank you for the help QHarr