# VBA Macro in excel to search a URL using Chrome for value and return 1 if found a match

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in Excel that will search the URLs in Column A for the respective value in B then return 1 in C if found a match.

The thing I need is to use google chrome as the URLs require a login which is already done in Chrome.

My URLs don't support IE, other browsers can be used such as Edge if that will make it easier.

Please see my code below and help me to make it work.

```
Sub ckWebSite()
Dim iText As String, HTML_Doc As Object, Param
Dim I As Long, httpObj As Object, ReqUrl As String
'
Set HTML_Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set httpObj = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
 
'
Param = Array("A", "B", "C")       '<<< Url column, Keywork Column, Flag Column
'
For I = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, Param(0)).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(I, Param(2)).ClearContents
    HTML_Doc.Clear ' = Empty
    ReqUrl = Cells(I, Param(0)).Value
        HTML_Doc.body.innerHTML = (chromePath & " -url " & ReqUrl).responseText
           
    iText = HTML_Doc.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText
    If InStr(1, iText, Cells(I, Param(1)).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Cells(I, Param(2)) = 1
    Else
        Cells(I, Param(2)) = 0
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915325/open-google-chrome-from-vba-excel

Comment: I was able to open chrome on the desired page but my issue how to interact with it and search for the required value.